# How to properly use setNeedsDisplay()

Tags: ios, swift

In my program, I am using a slider to change the alpha level of the currently selected color.
 When the slider changes its value, it calls my `setColor()` method to update the current color with the new alpha value and to update the uiview which displays the current color.
 Inside of this function, I am also trying to update my custom uiview, which is the powerButton as seen below. 
I change the color of the inner ring and then redraw it by calling `setNeedsDisplay()`. 
The more I slide and change the color, the program begins to lag more and more. 
Is this because of the constant redrawing? Is there a better way to do this? 
Also, does `setNeedsDisplay()` draw over the previous drawing or does it actually update?

```
  @IBAction func brightnessSliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        let currentVal = Int(sender.value)
        let alpha = CGFloat(Int(currentVal)) * 0.01
        brightnessLabel.text = String(currentVal) + "%"
        setColor(currentColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(alpha))
    }
    func setColor(color: UIColor) {
            let alpha = CGFloat(Int(lightBrightnessSlider.value)) * 0.01
            currentColor = color.colorWithAlphaComponent(alpha)
            colorView.backgroundColor = currentColor
            if powerState {
                powerButton.statusColor = currentColor
                powerButton.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }
```

And what the custom UIView class and function looks like

```
@IBDesignable

class PowerButton: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var buttonColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    @IBInspectable var statusColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let desiredLineWidth:CGFloat = 3

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        drawFillCircle()
        drawRing()
        drawInnerCircle()
    }
    internal func drawFillCircle()->() {

        let halfSize:CGFloat = min( bounds.size.width/2, bounds.size.height/2)                

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(
        arcCenter: CGPoint(x:halfSize,y:halfSize),
        radius: CGFloat( CGFloat(halfSize) - (desiredLineWidth / 2)),
        startAngle: CGFloat(0),
        endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2),
        clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

        shapeLayer.fillColor = statusColor.CGColor

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

[image: Example of the lag that occurs the more I change the color value]

Comment: It really isn't clear what the rest of your view is doing. It is likely the case that you do not need to use `setNeedsDisplay()` when changing the background colour. Could you post the `drawRect` method your are using ?

Comment: Added the custom UIView class with the only function that is relevant, drawFillCircle(). This draws the circle with the color in-between the white ring and white inner circle.

Answer (score 2):

Your app lags because you're adding a shape layer in every call of `drawRect()`. Thus, the layer hierarchy becomes larger and larger.

You should add the shape layer only once, and merely change its colors and the path.

Comment: So how would I go about doing that. I change the color value, but wouldn't it need to be redrawn to update the color on screen?

Comment: The layer should be redrawn if you change its properties. You should reference to the layer by a property of class `PowerButton`.

Comment: Wouldn't changing its fillColor justify as a change in its properties, requiring me to redraw the layer?

Comment: Never mind. Problem has been solved by making shapeLayer its own variable and updating the fill color directly. Thank you @macmoonshine